Оценка кода C++
Дорогие опытные программисты, если вам не трудно - посмотрите пожалуйста на написанный мною код текстового редактора (самого примитивного). Я старался его написать в стиле ООП. Для меня будет важна любая критика. Напишите, пожалуйста, противно ли вам смотреть на данный код?
Код:
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h> 
#include <string>
#include <fstream> 
#include <io.h>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <Windows.h>

#define CTRLF 6
#define ESC 27
#define s 115
#define ENTER 13
#define BACKSPACE 8

using namespace std;

class TextRedactor {

private:

    string path;
    string input_file;
    ifstream input;
    ofstream write;
    string data;

    void start() {
        cout << "Пожалуйста, введите путь до текстового файла (расширение .txt)" << endl;
        cin >> this->path;

        // Проверяем наличие расширения ".txt" в пути к файлу
        while (this->path.find(".txt") == string::npos) {
            cout << "Указанный файл не является текстовым файлом (.txt)\n";
            cout << "Пожалуйста, введите путь до текстового файла с расширением .txt\n";
            cin >> this->path;
        }

        // Проверяем существование файла
        while (_access(this->path.c_str(), 0) != 0) {
            cout << "Файл не найден\n";
            cout << "Пожалуйста, введите корректный путь до существующего файла\n";
            cin >> this->path;
        }

        // Открываем файл для чтения
        this->input.open(this->path, std::ios::in);
        if (!this->input.is_open()) {
            cout << "Не удалось открыть файл\n";
            // Можно выбрать, завершить программу или запросить новый путь к файлу
            exit(0);
        }

        // Считываем данные из файла
        string line;
        while (getline(this->input, line))
            this->data += line + "\n";

        this->input.close();
    }
    // реализуем логику завершения программы
    void exitProgram() {
        cout << "Вы действительно хотите завершить работу(ввите enter)?\n";
        int ans;
        ans = _getch();
        if (ans == ENTER) {
            system("cls");
            cout << this->data << endl;
            cout << "Сохранить изменения - enter, не сохранять - esc.\n";
            ans = _getch();
            if (int(ans) == ENTER) {
                this->write.open(this->path, std::ios::out);
                this->write << this->data;
                this->write.close();
                cout << "Изменения сохранены...\n";
                exit(0);
            }
            else {
                cout << "Изменения не сохранены.\n" << "Завершение работы...\n";
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        else
            return;
    }
    // функция вывода "изменений" на экран. Цветом подствечиваем важные данные
    void print_changes(const vector<pair<size_t, size_t>>& pos) {
        HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO consoleInfo;
        WORD savedAttributes;
        GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &consoleInfo);
        savedAttributes = consoleInfo.wAttributes;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < this->data.size(); ++i) {
            bool found = false;
            for (const auto& p : pos) {
                if (i >= p.first && i <= p.second) {
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_RED); // изменить цвет текста на фиолетовый
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, savedAttributes); // восстановить исходный цвет текста
            }
            cout << this->data[i];
        }

        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, savedAttributes); // восстановить исходный цвет текста
        cout << endl;
    }
    // вставка строки в начало
    void start_insert(const string& ch) {
        this->data = ch + this->data;
    }
    // удаление последнего символа
    void pop_back() {
        if (this->data.length() > 0)
            this->data.pop_back();
    }
    // Дополнительная функция для алгоритма КМП для поиска подстрок в строке - префиксная функция
    static vector<int> computePrefixFunction(const string& pattern) {
        int m = pattern.length();
        vector<int> pi(m, 0);
        int k = 0;
        for (int q = 1; q < m; ++q) {
            while (k > 0 && pattern[k] != pattern[q]) {
                k = pi[k - 1];
            }
            if (pattern[k] == pattern[q]) {
                ++k;
            }
            pi[q] = k;
        }
        return pi;
    }
    // Основная функция поиска в строке
    void findSubstrings(const string& pattern) { // Алгоритм КМП
        vector<pair<size_t, size_t>> indices;
        int n = this->data.length();
        int m = pattern.length();
        vector<int> pi = computePrefixFunction(pattern);
        int q = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            while (q > 0 && pattern[q] != this->data[i]) {
                q = pi[q - 1];
            }
            if (pattern[q] == this->data[i]) {
                ++q;
            }
            if (q == m) {
                indices.push_back({ i - m + 1, i });
                q = pi[q - 1];
            }
        }
        print_changes(indices);
    }

public:
    // Логика программы
    void run() {

        setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
        start();

        char ipt;
        string line;
        cout << this->data << endl;

        while (true) {

            cout << "Введите ctrl + f для поиск в строке, s для вставки строки в начало, backspace для удаления последнего символа.\n";
            ipt = _getch();

            switch (int(ipt)) {

                case ESC:
                    exitProgram();
                    break;

                case CTRLF:

                    cout << "Введите строку для поиска (нажмите esc для выхода)...\n";
                    ipt = _getch();

                    while (int(ipt) != ESC) {
                        
                        line += ipt;
                        
                        if (int(ipt) == BACKSPACE && line.length() > 1) {
                            line = line.substr(0, line.length() - 2);
                        }
                        system("cls");
                        cout << "Поиск: " << line << endl;
                        if (line.length() > 0) {
                            findSubstrings(line);
                            ipt = _getch();
                        }
                        else if (line.length() == 0) {
                            while (int(ipt) == BACKSPACE) {
                                system("cls");
                                cout << "Введите строку для поиска (нажмите esc для выхода)...\n";
                                cout << this->data << endl;
                                ipt = _getch();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    line = "";
                    cout << this->data << endl;
                    break;
                
                case s: 
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "Введите строку для вставки в начало..." << endl;
                    getline(cin, line);
                    if (line.empty())
                        getline(cin, line);
                    start_insert(line);
                    print_changes({ { 0, line.length() - 1} });
                    line = "";
                    break;

                case BACKSPACE:
                    system("cls");
                    pop_back();
                    cout << this->data << endl;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    TextRedactor Redactor;
    Redactor.run();
    return 0;
}


Мелкие придирки, сверху вниз:

<Windows.h> -> <windows.h> (с маленькой буквы). Это важно только в одном случае, при кросс-компиляции (компиляции под одну ОС из под другой). На линуксе имена к файлам регистрозависимые, а windows.h в MinGW называется с маленькой буквы.
Вроде мелочь, но иногда этим грешат даже серьезные программы.

Макросы как константы - лучше constexpr переменные. (#define s - ужс). Какие-то популярные символы, вроде '\n' и '\b' можно было бы писать прямо так, не делая именованные константы.

using namespace std; - не самая лучшая привычка. Сложнее на глаз определить, где символ из стандартной библиотеки а где нет, и иногда вызывает конфликты имен с ней. What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

Непонятно, зачем везде писать this->, но допустим, что это такой стиль.

while (this->path.find(".txt") == string::npos) - неправильно, правильно path.ends_with(".txt").

Проверьте, работает ли у вас кириллица в путях к файлам, на винде с этим бывают проблемы.


// Проверяем существование файла
while (_access(this->path.c_str(), 0) != 0) {

Непонятно зачем. Если файла нет, то .open() и так выдаст ошибку.


// Считываем данные из файла
string line;
while (getline(this->input, line))
    this->data += line + "\n";

Я бы советовал считать одним махом, так:
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << input.rdbuf();
std::string data = std::move(ss).str();


system("cls") - выглядит затратно запускать целое приложение (cls), только чтобы очистить экран. Я бы попробовал что-то из этого: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/clearing-the-screen (на первый взгляд (3) лучше всего, или (1)).

Поиск подстроки: возможно стоит использовать готовый std::search, если это не в учебных целях.

В перемешку разные стили наименования функций: foo_bar и fooBar. Лучше выбрать один.



Более существенные замечания:

Я бы посмотрел в сторону pdcurses, чтобы работало не только на винде.
В какой кодировке сохраняется и читается кириллица? (Она вообще работает?) Сейчас в моде UTF-8, но тут явно не он.
Скорее всего один длинный std::string будет тормозить на больших файлах. Как можно оптимизировать? Возоможно хранить вектор отдельных строк, но наверное есть способы еще лучше.
Если уж делать свои функции работы со строками, то можно вынести их в отдельный файл и/или неймспейс, чтобы потом можно было использовать повторно.


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)

Ну, #define-s это точно не ужас. При известной квалификации с помощью других макросов из них можно делать такие вещи (самое простое -- стрингификация), которые из constexpr без дополнительного кода не сделать. (я уже молчу про стоимость обратной совместимости с Си (это если потребуется втащить крестовый код в сишный проект))

@avp Я не говорю что они в целом ужас, конкретно макрос с именем s.
